# What football stadium is at the highest altitude in the world?

Tags: football, trivia, venues

After Brazil's goalless draw against Bolivia during 2018 World Cup Qualifiers, which was played on Estadio Hernando Siles Stadium, La Paz, [the Brazilian players needed some oxygen refreshment](https://www.thesun.co.uk/sport/football/4624424/brazil-players-oxygen-bolivia-neymar-philippe-coutinho-gabriel-jesus/) after their game at such a high altitude.

According to [the Wikipedia article about this stadium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estadio_Hernando_Siles),

> The stadium is located at an altitude of **3,637 metres (11,932 feet)** above sea level, making it one of the highest professional stadiums in the world.

Is this stadium the one at highest altitude? If not, which professional football stadium is the highest located stadium in the world?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Estadio Hernando Siles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estadio_Hernando_Siles) is not the highest stadium in the world. [Estadio Víctor Agustín Ugarte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estadio_V%C3%ADctor_Agust%C3%ADn_Ugarte), another stadium in Bolivia, is even higher with an altitude of 3,960 meters (12,992 ft).

However, the highest stadium in the world is [Estadio Daniel Alcides Carrión](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estadio_Daniel_Alcides_Carri%C3%B3n) located in Peru with an altitude of 4,380 meters (13,973 ft) above sea level. This stadium is used by football team [Unión Minas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uni%C3%B3n_Minas).